# How change just some characters from my label to bold?

Tags: delphi, label, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm trying to make a Rectangle to show some information. Inside this Rectangle I have a lot of labels, and in this labels I want to show some texts in bold. For example: 'Name:' <- Bold, and after this not bold.

If this is not possible, how can I know the size in pixels of a label.text? If I have this information, I can create two label and set the position of the second to be: `label2.position.X := label1.textWidth;`

Thanks!

Comment: The easiest solution is to use separate labels.

Comment: I'm creating this in run time, so, if I use 2 labels, I need to know where the text of the first ends. How can I know this?

Comment: label1.Canvas.TextWidth(label1.Caption)

Comment: Or, by default Labels have auto-size enabled.

Comment: You could set `Label2.Position.X := Label1.Position.X + Label1.Width` after assigning `Label1.Caption`. A better option would be to place the two Labels on a [`TRelativePanel`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.WinXCtrls.TRelativePanel) and then you can set `Label2.RightOf = Label1` so it stays to the right of Label1 regardless of any changes to Label1's width. See [Using the Relative Panel](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_the_Relative_Panel).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Remy but I think the auto-size is a much easier answer.

Comment: @DiegoBittencourt: not really, since you are doing the calculating and positioning manually at runtime in code, when FMX can do it for you automatically, and it can be configured at design-time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the standard label control your only option is to use *two* such controls, one with `Font.Style` including **fsBold**, the other not.

Place your first, bold label then as long as you leave/set the `AutoSize` property **true**, the `Width` property will tell you the width:

```
// Where:
//
//   - boldLabel is a created, initialised and positioned
//      label with bold text 
//
//   - normalLabel is a created and initialised label which 
//      has not yet been positioned (horizontally)
//
//   - spacingPixels is the distance you wish to maintain
//      between the two

normalLabel.Position.X := boldLabel.Position.X + boldLabel.Width + spacingPixels;
```

There are a number of 3rd party label controls, many of them free + open source (for VCL [*see below*]), which support varying degrees of markup in a label.  There may be similar implementations for FMX.

For VCL projects you might want to check out [the JediVCL library](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/) which includes a label supporting not just bold but other, albeit limited HTML markup.  If this is of interest, the control you are looking for in that library is [TJvHTLabel](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvHTLabel).

**NB. For future ref:**  You don't specify whether your project is FMX or VCL but it appears from the use of the `Position` property that it is likely to be FMX.  For issues involving controls, the framework in use can be a significant factor and should be mentioned to avoid eliciting answers that may not be relevant.